# Microsoft is "de-emphasizing" Silverlight, should I pick another technology (Flash or HTML 5)?

Tags: silverlight, flash, html

I have been planning since Summer to build a new hobby site over Christmas break in which I will use Silverlight to make some super-awesome navigation menu.  I was crushed to read that [Microsoft is de-emphasizing Silverlight](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/paul-thurrotts-wininfo/Microsoft-Embraces-HTML-5-Deemphasizes-Silverlight.aspx) (to throw all their weight into HTML 5 I guess).

I have never used Silverlight, but I am trying to build my development skills around Microsoft products, and Silverlight seems like a really cool technology, thus my interest.  If it is not going to have Microsoft's full support I am a bit apprehensive about committing to it.

With that said I have some questions:

1.) At this point in time can I get roughly the same results from HTML 5 as I could Silverlight when creating my navigation menu and with roughly the same amount of effort?

2.) If HTML 5 cannot fill the shoes of Silverlight at this time then what (Flash)?

3.) Is my apprehension about Silverlight even justified (would you use it now)?

Comment: "I am trying to build my development skills around Microsoft products"  Why?  Build your skills around solving problems using the most appropriate tool out there.

Comment: closed question, but this might shed some light on whats going on. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/15857/did-microsoft-kill-silverlight-closed

Comment: @Ed Swangren You don't consider Visual Studio an appropriate tool?  @GSto why would you close this?  Question 2 and 3 may contain a bit of opinion from the person answering, but question 1 can have a concrete answer.

Comment: @typo: I think GSto is referring to the link he included in his comment, which leads to a closed question.

Comment: @Dave Swersky Ahh, I see now.  Forums get me up in arms easy... my mistake.

Comment: Navigation is absolutely the worst feature to implement using a plug-in. For accessibility, usability and SEO, always use plain links (potentially with progressive enhancement scripts if you want it fancy).

Comment: @typoking: Of course it is, but that is not what you said.  You said; "I am trying to build my dev. skills around MS products".  That is the wrong way to steer a career.  These API's won't be around forever, and if you base your merit as an engineer on how well you use a specific set of tools and API's, you will be left behind.  Solve interesting problems.

Comment: @Ed Swangren I think you are taking what I said out of context.  Solving problems means using tools, and with the plethora of tools out there I think it would be better to master one set of tools (those provided by Microsoft) than to become a jack of all trades. I still use tools and environments other than those provided by Microsoft, but I want to put on a resume that **I know** MS tools, not that I have dabbled with everything under the Sun without mastering anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would point you to these two posts:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/11/01/silverlight-is-dead-long-live-silverlight.aspx 
http://team.silverlight.net/announcement/pdc-and-silverlight/

In summary, Silverlight is not going away.  Microsoft is recognizing the true cross-platform potential of HTML 5, but the spec for that isn't even complete yet, and we've got years before there is consistent support for it across the most popular browsers.  Silverlight is the basis for development on Windows Phone 7, which is a bet-the-farm play for Microsoft.

Speaking for myself, I'm getting ready to develop an entire ERP in Silverlight.

Comment: Those links really helped, I feel at ease.  It is also good to know that someone with a big number next to their name has no fear of using Silverlight.  I guess I'll stick to my original plan and hope for the best in the future.

Comment: @typo: I'm hedging my bets and learning HTML 5 soon, but that's a long-term architectural/strategic move.  HTML 5 won't *replace* Silverlight for existing apps, but some apps may slowly migrate from Silverlight to HTML5 over the course of the next few years.

Answer (score 4):

This was simply [unaltered tech journalism](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-our-strategy-with-silverlight-has-shifted/7834) which may have focused a bit much on the face value, without further probing and questioning which was courtesy of Mary J Foley. Read the [BobMu](http://team.silverlight.net/announcement/pdc-and-silverlight/) post.

Let me sum up the HTML5 vs Silverlight debate saying this...use Silverlight to build web apps, and HTML5 to build web sites.

Silverlight is moving forward just as it was pre-PDC. Ignore the hype, it is just that...hype.